# How to make the TortoiseHg workbench uncheck all files in the commit window

Tags: mercurial

Using the TortoiseHg workbench, when I switch to the commit window, all the files that I have changed locally are checked for commit.  I often select a file (not changing the check) to see what the diff is. Since that is the only file in my mind, I type a comment and hit commit, realizing that I have committed all of the changed files!

Is there a way to change the behavior to not check the files by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  The best you can do is hit the box at the top of the column to clear everything before doing anything else.  (Checked against THG v2.5.)